# Can I have AWS Glue Databrew update a Redshift table instead of create a new one every time the job runs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-databrew

We are looking to implement AWS Glue Databrew for our analysts to have more control over datasets they want to create and then use.  When testing, I have found that I can have the output go to Redshift and create a new table every time the job runs, but as you can imagine this will get messy.  Is there a setting for Redshift output that will update an existing table in Redshift instead of creating a new one everytime?

[When Redshift is the output option, there is no settings button to change from create new table to replace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pL8r.png)
[When s3 is the output option, the settings button reappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6est.png)
[Settings pop-up that appears when you press the settings button that appears with s3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPU1C.png)